# How to parse an attribute?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

How could I parse a value from data-value?

```
<a href="example.com" data-ref="TopRates" data-type="price" data-value="1212749" data-changescale="1" data-market-id="curr_one" data-symbol="curr_one">curr_one</a>
```

Here I have an example of script, it is searching for the first span which has bullish-color class and show on the screen what was there in that span. How should I parse a value from data-value and show it on the screen from the example above?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
Options.add_argument('--headless')
Options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
Options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

url = "http://example.com"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = Options, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
browser.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="html.parser")
a = soup.find("span", {"class": "bullish-color"})
print(a.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work by doing this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> page = '''<a href="http://example.com" data-ref="TopRates" data-type="price" data-value="1212749" data-changescale="1" data-market-id="curr_one" data-symbol="curr_one">curr_one</a>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features="html.parser")
>>> a = soup.find('a')
>>> a.attrs
{'data-changescale': '1', 'data-value': '1212749', 'data-market-id': 'curr_one', 'data-type': 'price', 'href': 'http://example.com', 'data-symbol': 'curr_one', 'data-ref': 'TopRates'}
>>> 
>>> a.attrs['data-value']
'1212749'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Selector which is much faster.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<a href="example.com" data-ref="TopRates" data-type="price" data-value="1212749" data-changescale="1" data-market-id="curr_one" data-symbol="curr_one">curr_one</a>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('a[data-value]')['data-value'])
```

**Output**:

```
1212749
```

---

In your case this should work.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('a[data-value]')['data-value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the element, you can get the attribute value by:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="example.com" data-ref="TopRates" data-type="price" data-value="1212749" data-changescale="1" data-market-id="curr_one" data-symbol="curr_one">curr_one</a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

print (soup.find('a')['data-value'])
```

**Output:**

```
1212749
```